# ModelForm in Django - Foreign Key Won't Save

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following models:

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.business_name

class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, blank=True)
```

and am trying to make a form for users to input an employee. Each user has exactly one business, and each business can have multiple employees. I am trying to have the form save the employee and the business name. I've managed to have the form show a text field for the employee and a drop down for hte business name. However, when the form is processed by the following code in the view, it does not save the employee with a link to the business -- the business just shows up as null, even when it is selected in the dropwdown menu.

```
def business_home(request):
    b = Business.objects.get(business_name='Cleaners')
    context_dict = {
                    'employee_name_form': EmployeeNameForm(initial={'business': b})}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeNameForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            print(form.save())

            w = form.save()
            w.business.save()
            w.save()
```

Though when I print out the cleaned data in the form, it is clear that it is reading in both the employee and the business data, and form.save() returns the object that I would like to write to the database -- the employee linked with the correct business.

Any idea why it might not be saving?

Here is my form:

```
class EmployeeNameForm(forms.models.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('employee_name', 'business')
        widgets = {
            'employee_name': forms.fields.TextInput(attrs={
                'placeholder': 'Enter the name of the employee you wish to add',
                'class': 'form-control input-lg',
                }),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EmployeeNameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Whats the output of `form.cleaned_data` after form is valid and `w.business` on printing?

Comment: form.cleaned data gives us a dict with the entered data: `{'employee name': 'Someone', 'business': <Business: Awesome Business>}` .

Comment: w.business gives the str form of an Employee object -- which I have set to be `str(self.employee_name) + ' - ' + str(self.business)`, so in this case, `Someone - Awesome Business`

Comment: Why are you overriding `__init__` in form if you're just calling `super` here and not doing anything else? Also, you're calling `form.save()` twice, that will create objects in your database.

Comment: It does create objects in my database, that is not the problem -- the problem is that the objects in the db do not have the foreign key set.

Comment: Based on the output of `w.business`,  `business` attribute has been set as `.save()` on a modelform saves the object in db. Just comment  out the last 2 lines   `w.business.save()` `w.save()` and see.

Comment: That does not work unfortunately, @Rahul

Comment: But i do not understand what do you mean by foreignkey is not set as `w.business` is printing the correct output which means that `business` attribute has been set correctly. Try fetching the `w` object  from the db after `form.save()` and check the `business` attribute.

Comment: Ahhhh looks like it was an unrelated template error that was producing this.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  To add to what has been said, you should not be saving business, business has to exist already in the database in order to appear in the dropdown.  When the the user submits the employee form, you just do:  if form.is_valid():  form.save() .. you should not need to do anything else there.